# Three Card Monte game using Java

Tags: java, game, playing-cards

I made a Three Monte Card game using Java

Problem:

> This is the original "ball and cups" game where you try to find out which cup has the ball under it. You may play with three cups and a ball, three cards (two jacks and an ace), or three doors and a car. Basically, randomly select a cup to hide the "ball". Let the player guess which cup hides the ball. The player wins if they guess correctly.

Problem taken from:

> https://programmingbydoing.com/a/three-card-monte.html

My code:

```
/*
 * Code by CLint
 */


import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThreeCardMonte {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int userInput;

        int randomN = random.nextInt(3)+1;

        System.out.println("You slide up to Fast Eddie's card table and plop down your cash.\n" +
                "He glances at you out of the corner of his eye and starts shuffling.\n" +
                "He lays down three cards.\n");
        System.out.println("Which one is the ace?\n" +
                "\t##\t##\t##\n" +
                "\t##\t##\t##\n" +
                "\t1\t2\t3");
        System.out.print("\n> ");
        userInput = input.nextInt();

        if (userInput == randomN) {
            if (randomN == 1) {
                System.out.println("\nYou nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.\n" +
                        "\tAA\t##\t##\n" +
                        "\tAA\t##\t##\n" +
                        "\t1\t2\t3");
            } else if (randomN == 2) {
                System.out.println("\nYou nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.\n" +
                        "\t##\tAA\t##\n" +
                        "\t##\tAA\t##\n" +
                        "\t1\t2\t3");
            } else if (randomN == 3) {
                System.out.println("\nYou nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.\n" +
                        "\t##\t##\tAA\n" +
                        "\t##\t##\tAA\n" +
                        "\t1\t2\t3");
            }
        }

        if (userInput != randomN) {
            if (randomN == 1) {
                System.out.println("\nHa! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number 1.\n" +
                        "\tAA\t##\t##\n" +
                        "\tAA\t##\t##\n" +
                        "\t1\t2\t3");
            } else if (randomN == 2) {
                System.out.println("\nHa! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number 2.\n" +
                        "\t##\tAA\t##\n" +
                        "\t##\tAA\t##\n" +
                        "\t1\t2\t3");
            } else if (randomN == 3) {
                System.out.println("\nHa! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number 3.\n" +
                        "\t##\t##\tAA\n" +
                        "\t##\t##\tAA\n" +
                        "\t1\t2\t3");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The output:

> [image: Code Output]

PS: I am open for corrections to make my code for efficient and clean.

Comment: there is not much left for efficency since this program flow is linear.

Answer (score 4):

### [single responsibility](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Single_Responsibility_Principle_SRP)

your class does all things together

- reading user input
- printing dialogs
- handle game logic

by this you violate the [openClosed principle](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-4-green/#Open_Closed_Principle). If you want to change your code (eg. play a one of **four** game) you have to make a lot of changes. If you want to add handling for `InputExceptions` ([see `Scanner.nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())  you would find the proper place. **Make Classes for each responsibility!**

### minor issues

- [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)): `(3)+1`
- hardcoded Strings (put them in a language file) - that also helps to [separate concerns](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-2-orange/#Separation_of_Concerns_SoC) between dialogs and logic
- [redundancy](https://refactoring.guru/smells/duplicate-code) (**use a formatter** for the text from the language files)

Answer (score 1):

## Constants

A couple of constants would make your code easier to adapt.  So, for example a constant for the number of cards would allow the potential to adapt the program to 2/4 card play.

## Variable naming

To make the program easier to follow, I favour names that indicate what a variable represents, rather than where it comes from.  So, rather than `randomN`, consider `acePosition`.  Rather than `userInput`, consider `guessedPosition`.

## Duplicated logic

When you're doing things that are identical / very similar it's a good indication that there's scope to extract into a function / class.  There are two main duplications that you've got, when printing out each of the winning/losing statements with the card positions.  These also share printing the end card positions.  Consider extracting a method that can output the card positions, with the ace in a given position.

## If/Else

When you've got two if conditions that are exclusive, use if/else, rather than `if(userInput == randomN)` and `if(userInput != randomN)`

## Putting it together

You might end up with something more like this:

```
public class ThreeCardMonte {
    final static int UNKNOWN_POSITION = 0;
    final static int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 3;

    public static String formatCards(int acePosition) {
        var cardValue = IntStream.range(0, NUMBER_OF_CARDS)
                .mapToObj(i -> i + 1 == acePosition ? "\tAA" : "\t##")
                .collect(Collectors.joining()) + "\n";
        var columnLabels = IntStream.range(0, NUMBER_OF_CARDS)
                .mapToObj(i->"\t"+(i+1))
                .collect(Collectors.joining()) + "\n";

        return cardValue + cardValue + columnLabels;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int acePosition = random.nextInt(NUMBER_OF_CARDS) + 1;


        System.out.println("You slide up to Fast Eddie's card table and plop down your cash.\n" +
                "He glances at you out of the corner of his eye and starts shuffling.\n" +
                "He lays down three cards.\n");
        System.out.println("Which one is the ace?\n" + formatCards(UNKNOWN_POSITION));
        System.out.print("> ");
        int guessedPosition = input.nextInt();

        if (guessedPosition == acePosition) {
            System.out.println("\nYou nailed it! Fast Eddie reluctantly hands over your winnings, scowling.\n" +
                    formatCards(acePosition));
        } else {
            System.out.format("\nHa! Fast Eddie wins again! The ace was card number %d.\n" +
                    formatCards(acePosition), acePosition);
        }
    }
}
```